# Go using for write to file bytes optimize in golang

Tags: arrays, file, go, byte

I have the following program that prints out information about each certificate in a `.pem` file:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    //for dev purposes set to 256
    const SignatureLength int = 256

    certPEMBlock, err := ioutil.ReadFile("testsign.crt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var blocks [][]byte
    for {
        var certDERBlock *pem.Block
        certDERBlock, certPEMBlock = pem.Decode(certPEMBlock)
        if certDERBlock == nil {
            break
        }

        if certDERBlock.Type == "CERTIFICATE" {
            blocks = append(blocks, certDERBlock.Bytes)
        }
    } //end for

    //OPEN FILE TO APPEND CERT INFORMATION INTO
    f, err := os.OpenFile("appendMe.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, block := range blocks {
        cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(block)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }

        //APPEND CERT INFO TO FILE
        //VERSION
        if _, err := f.Write([]byte(strconv.Itoa(cert.Version))); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        //KEY ID
        if _, err := f.Write(cert.SubjectKeyId); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        //SIGNATURE LENGTH
        if _, err := f.Write([]byte(strconv.Itoa(SignatureLength))); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        //COMMON NAME
        if _, err := f.Write([]byte(cert.Subject.CommonName)); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

    } //end for

    //CLOSE THE FILE
    if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

it works, but notice that each line separately writes to the file.  That seems a bit wasteful, but I am not clear about options in Go...do I create an array...do I slice it from the cert...another for loop...

**QUESTION**

Instead of f.Write() on each line, what is the proper or alternative approach in Go?

Instead of using the cert.*, should I be capturing that data into a struct or array?

**Follow up**

let's say the last write or any write fails, does Go roll back changes or does last write not get written to the file?  This needs to be an all or nothing write.

(this is me learning as I do, thanks for your help)

Comment: What makes you think there's an issue with the number of writes? In regard to your second question, no, it writes what you tell it to when you tell it to, with no magic. If you want all-or-nothing writes, you'll have to write to a buffer in memory, then write that buffer to file at the end.

Comment: Adrian, if sample above appears fine to more seasoned Go programmers here, then I'm happy to be fine with it as well - it just left me feeling there was a better way.  I was thinking about the buffer approach as well, thanks

Comment: There's not any such thing as an "all or nothing" write. If you need the file write to be atomic, the only way (on posix) is to write a temp file and mv it over the original. Otherwise if you want to buffer your writes, then buffer them. That's what the `bufio` package is for.

Comment: There's a library for atomic writes: https://github.com/natefinch/atomic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to write to a buffer in memory is using the `bytes` package, which provides a `Buffer` type. Since `Buffer` implements [the `Writer` interface](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer), you can update your `Write` calls to use the `Buffer` instead, and then use the [`Buffer.WriteTo`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.WriteTo) method to write the accumulated data out to the file. Here's what that looks like, with the loops combined also:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    //for dev purposes set to 256
    const SignatureLength int = 256

    certPEMBlock, err := ioutil.ReadFile("testsign.crt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //OPEN FILE TO APPEND CERT INFORMATION INTO
    f, err := os.OpenFile("appendMe.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    for {
        var certDERBlock *pem.Block
        certDERBlock, certPEMBlock = pem.Decode(certPEMBlock)
        if certDERBlock == nil {
            break
        }

        if certDERBlock.Type == "CERTIFICATE" {
            cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(certDERBlock.Bytes)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                continue
            }

            //APPEND CERT INFO TO FILE
            //VERSION
            if _, err := buf.Write([]byte(strconv.Itoa(cert.Version))); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            //KEY ID
            if _, err := buf.Write(cert.SubjectKeyId); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            //SIGNATURE LENGTH
            if _, err := buf.Write([]byte(strconv.Itoa(SignatureLength))); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            //COMMON NAME
            if _, err := buf.Write([]byte(cert.Subject.CommonName)); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        }
    } //end for

    // write data accumulated in buf out to f
    buf.WriteTo(f)

    //CLOSE THE FILE
    if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```